# Flagging history - dark box around question title?

Tags: discussion

What does this box represent in my flagging history?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It indicates an answer that has now been deleted (see purple)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean/22185#22185).

You can verify this by trying to visit the link - if you're a <10k user, you won't find it, and if you are, the answer will be highlighted in a similar way to indicate that.